# Existence of solution of linear system with equality and inequality constraints

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

Given matrices $A$ ($n \times k$) and $C$ ($m \times $k), and vectors $b$ and $d$, I want to know if there is a value of $x$ that solves the two constraints below:

\begin{array}{c}
     A x = b \\
     C x \geq d
\end{array}

In case it helps, I already have a previous solution of $x$ that solves the first equation (the equality $Ax=b$), and I want to know if a solution that also solves $Cx \geq d$ exists.

Both matrices are potentially huge (e.g. 100,000 rows and/or 1,000 columns). There are no extra assumptions, so they might e.g. be ill-conditioned.

I suspect this might be solved with the [simplex method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) (but I haven't had any luck with this yet), or perhaps with a twist to [Farkas' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma), but I haven't had any luck yet.

I also found some related questions, but either they were incorrectly worded (and thus incorrectly answered), or had incorrect/useless responses. For instance,

- [Checking the existence of a solution for a set of linear equality and ineaulity equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337817/checking-the-existence-of-a-solution-for-a-set-of-linear-equality-and-ineaulity)
- [Linear least squares with inequality constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69613/linear-least-squares-with-inequality-constraints) (here, the linked paper, by Golub & Saunders, does not actually use inequality constraints but equality constraints).

Comment: Just solve a linear program with those constraints and zero objective.

Comment: Given that the system is potentially *huge*, is there a preferred way to do so? EG: solve a dual simplex? Also, are we leaving anything on the table by just running `min 0 s.t. ...` or in your experience this is fine? (I'm asking for "experience" question because a lot of the questions I saw before posting mine were either commented or answered by you)

Comment: Does your particular solution of $A x = b$ satisfy $C x \geq d$? If it does, problem solved.

Comment: It might or might not. If it does, then as you said we are done. This is actually one of the building blocks of a generalized linear model solver I'm working on (the part that check if a solution exists), so I need to be agnostic on the inputs I receive.

Also, I know that the simple case (where $Ax=b$ and $Cx = d$) does not hold (this is trivial to check and was done in an earlier stage).

Comment: You may want to take a look at chapter 5 of [Decision Procedures: An Algorithmic Point of View](https://books.google.com/books/about/Decision_Procedures.html?id=DRqRDQAAQBAJ). The book's [webpage](http://www.decision-procedures.org) should also be useful.